# Safari text jumps/flicker when changing margin-top

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit

I have this code:

```
            if (curTop > top )
            {
                $text.css("margin-top", Math.abs( rect.top ) + curY + "px");        
            }
            else
            {
                $text.css("margin-top", curY - Math.abs( rect.top ) + "px");            
            }
```

Where rect is:

```
            rect        = $text.get( 0 ).getBoundingClientRect();
```

and curY:

```
            var curY    = parseInt( $text.css( "margin-top" ) );
```

I believe that there is nothing wrong with that... because it works
in chrome and firefox... but I'm noobish at safari and I do not see why
it does the flickering...

In advance thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

This solver it but animated it, might work for others, it's perfect for me:

```
        if ( isSafari )
        {
            $text.css({ "-webkit-transition": "1s ease-in-out" });
        }
```